# UTF-8 encoding for Lua

Tags: utf-8, lua, coronasdk

I am developing an application with the Corona SDK. I want to send UTF-8 encoded text to the server and also decode the responses (also in UTF-8.)

Is somebody familiar with UTF-8 encoding and decoding functions that I can use?

Comment: Please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5155244/221509

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lua standard library doesn't have any functions dealing with UTF-8 characters. You'd have to use some external library (like ICU) or use an existing Lua binding for one.